# How to print variable as a string instead of as a count?

Tags: python

I am trying to search multiple text files for the count of 'plate appearances' which occurs when
    `temp_array2[0] == "play" and temp_array2[2] == "1"`:

I am trying to export this as a .csv file however, when I print the 'count of plate appearances' it appears as a count, not a string (and I think it needs to be a string to export to .csv).

The code I have got so far is below.

```
import os

input_folder = 'files'  # path of folder containing the multiple text files

# create a list with file names 
data_files = [os.path.join(input_folder, file) for file in                 
os.listdir(input_folder)]

# open csv file for writing
csv = open('myoutput.csv', 'w')  
def write_to_csv(line):
    print(line)
    csv.write(line)


j=0 # initialise as 0
count_of_plate_appearances=0 # initialise as 0


for file in data_files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:  # use context manager to open files
        for line in f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            i=0      
            while i < len(lines):
                temp_array = lines[i].rstrip().split(",")
                if temp_array[0] == "id":
                    j=0
                    count_of_plate_appearances=0
                    game_id = temp_array[1]
                    awayteam = lines[i+2].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    hometeam = lines[i+3].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    date = lines[i+5].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    output_for_csv=(game_id,date,hometeam, awayteam)
                    print(output_for_csv)
                    #csv.write(','.join(output_for_csv) + '\n') #write to the csv file. This works

                    for j in range(i+46,i+120,1): #only check for plate appearances this when temp_array[0] == "id"
                        temp_array2 = lines[j].rstrip().split(",") #create new array to check for plate apperances
                        if temp_array2[0] == "play" and temp_array2[2] == "1": # plate apperance occurs when these are true
                       count_of_plate_appearances=count_of_plate_appearances+1
                    #print(count_of_plate_appearances)
                    output_for_csv2=(game_id,date,hometeam, awayteam,[count_of_plate_appearances]) #this is what I want to outpu to the CSV
                    print(output_for_csv2) 
                    #csv.write(','.join(output_for_csv2) + '\n') #the code does not run when this is uncommented

                    i=i+1

                else:
                    i=i+1

                    j=0
                    count_of_plate_appearances=0
                #quit()


csv.close()
```

The output is as follows

```
('ARI201803300', '2018/03/30', 'ARI', 'COL')
('ARI201803300', '2018/03/30', 'ARI', 'COL', [35])
('ARI201803310', '2018/03/31', 'ARI', 'COL')
('ARI201803310', '2018/03/31', 'ARI', 'COL', [33])
('ARI201804020', '2018/04/02', 'ARI', 'LAN')
('ARI201804020', '2018/04/02', 'ARI', 'LAN', [32])
('ARI201804030', '2018/04/03', 'ARI', 'LAN')
('ARI201804030', '2018/04/03', 'ARI', 'LAN', [38])
('ARI201804040', '2018/04/04', 'ARI', 'LAN')
```

*note there are 2 lines of out put for each. The first one is without 'count of plate appearances' and this prints to pdf fine. The second line is what I want to print.

I think it should look like this in order to get the .csv output.

```
('ARI201803300', '2018/03/30', 'ARI', 'COL', '35')
('ARI201803310', '2018/03/31', 'ARI', 'COL', '33')
('ARI201804020', '2018/04/02', 'ARI', 'LAN', '32')
('ARI201804030', '2018/04/03', 'ARI', 'LAN', '38')
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: output_for_csv2=(game_id,date,hometeam, awayteam, str(count_of_plate_appearances))...

Note the str(count_of_plate_appearances)

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Thank you so much! Simple fix, I'm really new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to `str`, the problem is that you are inserting it as a `list`

```
output_for_csv2=(game_id,date,hometeam, awayteam,str(count_of_plate_appearances))
```